# Get zip from googleapi autocomplete request

Tags: google-maps, curl, google-api, httprequest

I am sending the following request to the google autocomplete api in attempts to get a street address with the zip code included.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=917&component=country:us&key=[MyApiKey]&types=address&bounds=defaultBounds&stricktBounds=true&address_components=postal_code&fields=address_components
```

I can't seem to figure out how to ask for the zip code in the query parameters. When I pass a full address with the zip in the input, google returns the zip code, but I would like it to always return the zip code.

I can make another request to the google maps api and pass the place id that I get from the autocomplete endpt and get the full address with the following request.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?fields=formatted_address&place_id=Eic1MDEgQ29sbGVnZSBBdmVudWUsIEdyZWVuc2Jvcm8sIE5DLCBVU0EiURJPCjQKMgldGdoYQBlTiBEjv0Tw4tNAARoeCxDuwe6hARoUChIJVXM4RSQZU4gRLNRdpst7vxAMEPUDKhQKEgmVWLxpQBlTiBGKDjnnY2NAzg&key=[my_Key]
```

But I would like to do a search and get the zip code all in one request.

**Edit:**
The following works in javascript with the google api javascript package, but I cannot use javascript in my project...

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/AutocompletionService.GetPredictions?1s501&fields=formatted_address&key=[my_key]
```

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The google api place textsearch endpoint can be used instead with field type formatted_address to return the zip code.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=971&fields=formatted_address&inputtype=textquery&key=[my_key]
```